# Excel Query looking up multiple values for the same name and presenting averages

Tags: excel, vlookup

Apologies if this has been asked before. I would be surprised if it hasn't but I am just not hitting the correct syntax to search and get the answer.

I have a table of raw data for my staff, it contains data on the name of the employee who completed a job and the start and finish times, among other things. I have no unique ID's other than name, and I cant change that as I'm part of a large organisation and I have to make do with the data I'm given.

what I would like to do it present a table (Table 2) that shows the name of the employee and then takes the start/finish times for all of their jobs on table 1 and presents the average time taken across all of their jobs.

I have used Vlookup in the past but I'm not sure it will cut it here. the raw data table contains approx 6000 jobs each month.

On table 1 i work out the time taken for each job with this formula;
=IF(V6>R6,V6-R6,24-R6+V6)   (R= started Time) (V= Completed Time) in 24hr clock.
I have gone this route as some jobs are started before midnight and completed afterwards. Although my raw data also contains dates (started/completed) in  separate columns so I am open to an experts feedback on this and if there is a better way to work out the total time form start to completion.

Comment: Can you share sample data?

Comment: unfortunately not as it contains patient information, I'll try to scrub that out but it might take a while.

Comment: how do upload a sample file?

Comment: You can share snap or  share a sample data by typing it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe the easiest way to tackle this would be with a Pivot Table. Calculate the time taken for each `Name` and `Job` combination in Table 1; create a pivot table with the `Name` in the `Row Labels` and the `Time` in the `Values` -- change the `Time` `Values` to be an `average` instead of a `sum`:

[image: Excel]

Alternatively, you could create a unique list of names, perhaps with `Data > Remove Duplicates` and then use an `=AVERAGEIF` formula:

[image: Excel AVERAGEIF]

Comment: Thanks again the pivot tables are just the trick. One quick question though. The raw data is in a spreadsheet with a tab for each month of the year. Is there a trick to having one pivot table that displays April-Marches figures or will I need a fresh table for each month? I could dump all 12 months worth of data in to the one tab but with 10k+ entries per month excel doesn't like that very much

Comment: @custhasno I would just place all of the entries in one large table with a column for `month_name`. 10K+ is not *that* big. You could then put the `month_name` either in the `Report Filter` spot of the `Pivot Table` or, better yet, you may want to use a `Slicer`: Pivot Table Tools > Options > Insert Slicer.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks this give me the thread to pull on, I have unique names as its the persons full name, but ill try pivot tables to hopefully make it a little more future proof for other things to be reports on later.